# In Visual Studio Code, why are src/pages linked together or appear together?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, gatsby, src

I'm new to Visual studio code (VSC) and I'm working through a Gatsby tutorial. Each time I've created a new directory, VSC links or appears to link src/pages together. I want pages to be a sub folder of src. Src should stand alone from other examples I've seen online. Is this common format? See below  [image: Visual Studio Code Interface]

Comment: Because `src/` only contains one sub-directory, `pages/`. The project does have the layout you want, that's just how VSC shows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pain in visual studio but you can change it by going to your user preferrences file (ctrl + shift + P) searching for preferences **Open Settings (JSON)** file and adding the following line **"explorer.compactFolders": false,** on settings.json file. Hit save and that's it!

When "explorer.compactFolders": true

[image]

When "explorer.compactFolders": false

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because the "src" folder doesn't contain files, just a "pages" folder